# Decrypting Blowfish/CBC in Java

Tags: java, perl, encryption, blowfish

I have Perl code that decrypts a String and I want to do the same in Java. This is the Perl code:

```
my $c = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => $keyString, -cipher => 'Blowfish', -header => 'randomiv');
return $c->decrypt_hex($config->{encrypted_password})
```

This is my attempt at the Java code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// setup an IV (initialization vector) that should be
// randomly generated for each input that's encrypted
byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

// decrypt
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(keyString), "Blowfish");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(input));
return Hex.encodeHexString(decrypted);
```

I'm getting:`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`. But according to [this](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC-2.24/CBC.pm), the `Crypt CBC` library uses `PKCS5` as the default padding.

Also, am I doing the hex encoding at the end right?

Comment: I see a lot of base 64 encoding/decoding on the Java side. Did you do that on the perl side too? Or did you just paste random crypto code? Padding errors happen when the final block does not decrypt; that happens if the block itself or the block before that was damaged or incorrect, or if the key is not binary compatible.

Comment: I've tried String.getBytes(), with a number of different encodings and that didn't seem to change the problem. I read that Base64 encoding/decoding may be more reliable, although that may be incorrect.

Comment: Ciphertext must be encoded if represented by a string. So in that sense it is more reliable. But you obviously cannot change any part of the algorithm if you want t be compatible with the Perl code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you have is that you generate a random IV instead of importing the one used for encryption. Do you have access to the IV used at encryption? Could it be at the start of the ciphertext?

Comment: I don't have access to the IV used at encryption. I assumed a random IV would work because that appears to be what the code I am trying to emulate is doing.

Comment: It might be put in front of the ciphertext. In that case the first block (the IV) may decrypt to garbage, but the next blocks should be OK. A random IV during decryption does not make much sense, a zeroed out IV does not add security, but it does make sense if the key is not reused.

Comment: Note that your comment makes absolutely no sense for the first block of ciphertext. You cannot retrieve the plaintext of that block if the IV is unknown and fully randomized; it is the same as encrypting the plain text of the first block with a one time pad before performing the encryption using the block cipher, and then throwing away the key. Perfect security, and no key. Not a good combination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do Perl, so I'm not quite sure if my response is valid. Base64 is probably not the right decoding you're looking for.

For creating your SecretKeySpec, try doing something like:

```
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes("ASCII"), "Blowfish");
```

For decoding the text, check out Hex.decodeHex(char[]) which can be found at http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html ... so your code might look something like this:

```
byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(input.toCharArray()));

String unencryptedStuff = new String(decrypted);
```

Comment: I changed the SecretKeySpec creation, but I'm still getting `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`.

Comment: I don't know how the key is encoded in Perl, but using String.getBytes for the key is terribly bad advise.

Comment: well, it's not too hard to switch over to utf-8 or something: keyString.getBytes("UTF-8")... my comment was to emphasize that base64 encoding is probably not what's happening in the perl code.